How to choose a relay?
I'm having trouble sourcing a 12V 20/30A SPDT relay (or similar) with flyback resistance that has BOTH a diode and resistor.  I need to protect my ECM on a vehicle as the ECM is directly providing the 12V trigger voltage for the relay.  I've read that having both a diode and resistor is the best option.  The relay will be energized when the ignition is on and de energized when the ignition is turned off so I'm not worried about having a small delay with the relay operating.  Thanks in advance.  Dave.

If you're not worried by a delay, why the resistor?  shopping questions are off topic, but try an automotive parts supplier. diode and resistor in series or in parallel?

I decided to go with a diode.  See below.  Thanks for the response!

I can't say I've ever seen a relay with both a diode and resistor built in, it's usually one, the other, or nothing, so you might just be on a wild goose chase.
A diode will clamp spikes better, but will also hold the relay energized a bit longer. A resistor will dissipate the energy faster, but will allow higher spike voltages. You'll probably want to get a relay with the diode for best protection and then maybe add a resistor externally although I'm not sure how much benefit you would get from it.

Thank you!  THAT is the answer that I really needed.  Much appreciated!

@DavidHeistuman Great. So you know, shopping questions are off topic, so asking where to source something will get your question closed, asking what to source should generally be okay as long as it's not too specific. I think it was mostly the title that got this one closed. Something to remember for future questions, how you ask matters.
